# Linear aproximation using only variables

Tags: calculus

yet again another school assignment. I have a hard time with conceptual math that only involves variables. I much prefer to have real values, but I need to learn!

I am pretty stuck, so baby steps would be very helpful!

Here it is:

Problem: Recall how in our last Maple lab (ignore this, it doesn't help in this particular problem) that we approximated sqrt(2) and cube root of 5 using linear approximations of certain functions. Let us suppose we want to approximate a number r
using a function f.

1. When you choose your function f, what should f(r) be?

I am unsure if I am supposed to use just r, or create a equation using r.

2. Suppose that your initial guess for r is a0. Find a formula for your next guess a1.
3. Now that you have a1, find a formula for your second guess a2 in terms of just a1 (not
   in terms of a0).
4. In general, if your current guess is a, estimate a formula for the next guess N(a).
5. By nding an appropriate function f (think trigonometry), and by using the formula
   you derived in #4, use Maple to help you estimate pi to 9 decimal places.

Note: You need to use your formula, not the equation for the tangent line.

formula: L(x) = f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)

Comment: This link might help you: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LinearApproximations.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Let us suppose we want to approximate $r$ with a function $f$, using the formula
$$L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot(x-a)$$

> 1. When we choose our function $f$, what should $f(r)$ be?

To use $L$ as a correct approximation for $r$, we need that $L(r)=0$, so immediatley $f(r)=0$. Otherwise, we couldn't approximate $r$ with the function!

> 2. Suppose that your initial guess for $r$ is $a_0$. Find a formula for your next guess $a_1$.

If $a_0$ is our initial guess, the equation gives: 
$$L(x)=f(a_0)+f'(a_0)\cdot(x-a_0)$$

As we need $L(r)=0$, let's force that condition:
$$0=f(a_0)+f'(a_0)\cdot(x-a_0)$$
Solving for $x$, note that this is a better guess, that is, $a_1$:
$$x=a_1=a_0-\frac{f(a_0)}{f'(a_0)}\qquad (1)$$

Note that this is the Newton's method to finding roots!

> 3. Now that you have $a_1$, find a formula for your second guess $a_2$ in terms of just $a_1$ (not in terms of $a_0$).

Following the same reasoning as the previous question, we should take $a_1$ as the input of $(1)$, so
$$a_2=a_1-\frac{f(a_1)}{f'(a_1)}$$

> 4. In general, if your current guess is $a$, estimate a formula for the next guess $N(a)$.

As previously stated, take the current guess as input for $(1)$, so
$$N(a)=a-\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}$$

> 5. By finding an appropriate function $f$ (think trigonometry), and by using the formula you derived in #4, use Maple to help you estimate $\pi$ to 9 decimal places.

Then, we should take a function $f$ such as $f(\pi)=0$, so, let 
$$f(x)=\sin(x)\Rightarrow f'(x)=\cos(x)$$
and:
$$N(a)=a-\frac{\sin(a)}{\cos(a)}$$

Comment: I would like to thank you very much! This helped me greatly, and I now understand what was being asked.

Comment: Glad it helped you!